# What is wrong with this Sunspot Solr setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am using [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/) to search my local db. After adding the gems, running the generate command, and booting up the solr server I do the following:

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :full_name, :brand_name
  searchable do
    text :full_name
    text :brand_name
  end
end
```

Added the above to my Style model and re-indexed (I had already indexed prior to creating this post, which is why I re-indexed to put it here)

```
funkdified@vizio ~/rails_projects/goodsounds.org $ rake sunspot:solr:reindex
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
*Note: the reindex task will remove your current indexes and start from scratch.
If you have a large dataset, reindexing can take a very long time, possibly weeks.
This is not encouraged if you have anywhere near or over 1 million rows.
Are you sure you want to drop your indexes and completely reindex? (y/n)
y
[#######################################] [14/14] [100.00%] [00:00] [00:00] [53.19/s]
```

Then I try a search and get nothing

```
1.9.3p392 :003 > Style.search { fulltext 'Monkey' }.results
  SOLR Request (10.4ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x0000000685ab28> parameters={data: fq=type%3AStyle&q=Monkey&fl=%2A+score&qf=full_name_text+brand_name_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
 => []
```

But, wait shouldn't it have worked and picked this up?

```
Style.first
  Style Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "styles".* FROM "styles" LIMIT 1
 => #<Style id: 54, brand_name: "Monkey", full_name "Monkey Chicken", created_at: "2013-02-01 23:25:58", updated_at: "2013-02-16 03:02:16">
```

Here is one more clue. I am seeing "unknown field" for brand_name (setup in Style.rb)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the schema (the "searchable" block) you have to either reindex all models:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

or reindex that specific model with a given batch size (here 500):

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex[500,Style]
```

as per the Sunspot [doco on Github](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) (search "Reindexing Objects").

FYI, to use `Style.reindex` for non-schema changes, you will have to call `Sunspot.commit` to save changes.

Comment: That's very strange - I actually built a Style model to match yours above, and it works fine with the default generated configuration. I'm assuming you are using either a Mac or Linux - sunspot_solr usually fails more spectacularly than that on PC. If you create a new app with just the style model in it and generate the settings using `rails g sunspot_rails:install` does it work?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Mint 14 (ubuntu quantal)

Comment: I suspect there is a gem conflict, but I can only find one conflicting gem.. and that's active admin http://mrdanadams.com/2012/beware-using-active_admin-and-sunspot-rails-gems-together/#.UYoRoEAW1tI which I'm not using

Comment: Does the searchable logic need to be placed anywhere specific in my style.rb file? I have it just after the belongs_to association logic

Comment: Searchable block should be fine there. If there was a conflicting gem, you should not see the SOLR request in the log. Field name would be 'brand_name_text' inside of Solr. Can you see the fields (and search terms) within the Schema Browser?

Comment: Hey man, I don't know why but it's started working. Maybe I just needed a reboot. Giving you the tick anyway for helping me out. Thanks.

Comment: I hate it when things go weird like that, but glad your project is working.